# Azure iot deviceId validation from Azure SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-iot-sdk

We use Azure SDK to create Resource groups, iot hubs and devices.

For example:

```
iotHubDescription = await iotHubClient.IotHubResource.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, iotHubName,
            iotHubDescription);
```

or

```
var device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(azureDevice.DeviceId));
```

I've found how to validate Iot Hub name before create it:

```
var info = await iotHubClient.IotHubResource.CheckNameAvailabilityAsync(new OperationInputs(iotHubName));
```

but can't find how to validate device id.

So, question is: How to validate Iot device id from Azure SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch using the [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.exceptions.devicealreadyexistsexception?view=azure-dotnet),

```
try
{
   simulatedDevice = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(simulatedDeviceId));}
   catch (DeviceAlreadyExistsException)
   {
    simulatedDevice = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(simulatedDeviceId);
    Console.WriteLine("Retrieving existing device id");
   }
}
```